# Wirelessly shoot photo from non-wifi webcam

Tags: wireless-networking, webcam, camera, timelapse

I'm planning to put my action camera at my backyard to perform time-lapse.

At the computer, I have a program called "TinCam".  Normally, I connect my camera to PC and TinCam takes photo from camera (camera works as webcam).

Now, I need to do that wirelessly, but the camera doesn't have timelapse or wifi function.

Answer (score -1):

Uhhhh well.. few ideas...

- build it a wireless controller with as cheap Pi.
- buy a really really really long usb extension cord to connect it to the computer.
- buy a cheap tablet, microusb <-> usb connector for it, and use the tablet as an access point.

Comment: I think tablets can't handle webcams. Maybe application called "IP Webcam" for android, would be perfect. I need to think about it.

Comment: @Fubz android tablets are linux, there are apps that can work with it.